# Update Plugin of wordpress to specific version

Tags: plugins

I'm not a wordpress developer but a friend asked to me if I could help him with some php scripts, The problem Is that I downgraded a plugin and now I want to roll back to a upper version because this is damaging the UI visuals, this plugin in effect Is elementor, I don't want to break this site rules but I just need to know how can I upgrade to the specific version that was before I downgraded not the one recommended on the plugin side bar of the admin page because this could break the UI even worse, How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a backup of the site, zip up the plugin's folder under wp-content/plugins/.  Add plugins, then upload zip file. Otherwise you may have to reach out to the plugin's author to ask if they have the version you need.

Comment: well i have the backup done with wp-all-in-one migration, just unpacked the .wpress file with node and saw that plugin folder So if i upldoad that to the wp-content/plugins this will automatically update the plugins to the version I had before? is there any risk of doing this?

Comment: Of course don't zip the entire "plugins" folder. Just the one subfolder you need.  You don't have to manually upload the zip file. Just click plugins then add plugin then choose upload zip file. No there's minimal risk of replacing a folder in the plugin directory especially if you back up first. It should ask you if you want to replace the current plugin.